# xsl prints child nodes on the line below where I want it

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, newline

This is my first post, so I hope I get formatting/details presented well.  Also, I'm really new to xml/xsl, but I've looked all over for an answer to this and haven't found anything.  I have data that I'm trying to get displayed all on the same line, but when I run xsltproc with the xsl file, the data gets spit out on the line below where I want it.

First, here's the output I'm getting:

```
$ xsltproc MyXSL.xsl MyData.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>

Measurement Information,Time Stamp:20120315150500.0+0000,Granularity Period:300,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,,DataElement1,,Suspect Flag
DEFAULT2
Measurement Information,Time Stamp:20120315150500.0+0000,Granularity Period:300,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,,DataElement2,,Suspect Flag
DEFAULT19
Measurement Information,Time Stamp:20120315150500.0+0000,Granularity Period:300,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,,DataElement3,,Suspect Flag
DEFAULT2
Measurement Information,Time Stamp:20120315150500.0+0000,Granularity Period:300,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,,DataElement4,,Suspect Flag
DEFAULT0
```

What I want is the following:

```
Measurement Information,Time Stamp:20120315150500.0+0000,Granularity Period:300,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,,DataElement1,DEFAULT,2,Suspect Flag
Measurement Information,Time Stamp:20120315150500.0+0000,Granularity Period:300,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,,DataElement2,DEFAULT,19,Suspect Flag
Measurement Information,Time Stamp:20120315150500.0+0000,Granularity Period:300,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,,DataElement3,DEFAULT,2,Suspect Flag
Measurement Information,Time Stamp:20120315150500.0+0000,Granularity Period:300,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,,DataElement4,DEFAULT,0,Suspect Flag
```

Here's the data I'm operating on, and the area I'm having trouble with is the children of the "mdc/md/mi/mv" fields, the "moid" and "r":

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MyXSL.xsl" ?>
<mdc xmlns:HTML="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml">
<md>
<mi>
    <mts>20120315150500.0+0000</mts>
    <gp>300</gp>
    <mt>DataElement1</mt>
    <mv>
        <moid>DEFAULT</moid>
        <r>2</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
<mi>
    <mts>20120315150500.0+0000</mts>
    <gp>300</gp>
    <mt>DataElement2</mt>
    <mv> 
        <moid>DEFAULT</moid> 
        <r>19</r> 
    </mv>
</mi>
<mi>
    <mts>20120315150500.0+0000</mts>
    <gp>300</gp>
    <mt>DataElement3</mt>
    <mv>
        <moid>DEFAULT</moid>
        <r>2</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
<mi>
    <mts>20120315150500.0+0000</mts>
    <gp>300</gp>
    <mt>DataElement4</mt>
    <mv>
        <moid>DEFAULT</moid>
        <r>0</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
</md>
</mdc>
```

Here's the xsl file I'm using to parse the xml:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mdc">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="md">
   <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mi">
Measurement Information,Time Stamp:<xsl:value-of select="mts"/>,Granularity Period:<xsl:value-of select="gp"/>,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,<xsl:for-each select="mt">,<xsl:value-of select="."/>,</xsl:for-each>,Suspect Flag
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mts">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gp">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mt">
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mv">
<xsl:value-of select="moid"/>
<xsl:for-each select="r">
<xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:value-of select="sf"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

All files were created/obtained through unix-only file systems, and I doubly made sure that this wasn't caused by line termination characters by running the input through sed -i 's/\r//g'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Still no luck, but some more information:  I tried adding normalize-space() around "moid" and "r", but that didn't work.  I also verified the same behavior through w3school's xslt tryit editor

Comment: Not only are they on the next line, they're out of order too.  I.e. if it were _only_ a whitespace problem the `Suspect Flag` text would appear AFTER the `DEFAULTx` text.  Go back and reconsider this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified stylesheet that creates the output you posted as the wanted result:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="mi">
  <xsl:text>Measurement Information</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*[not(*)]"/>
  <xsl:text>,Suspect Flag&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mts">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>Time Stamp:</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="gp">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>Granularity Period:</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>,Measurement Values,Object Instance ID,</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mt | mv/*">
  <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```